# Turning down volume on multiple music files

Tags: audio, conversion, music

I am using my android phone to play mp3 and flac files that i have stored on a microSD crad. The problem is that android only has 10 volume levels, and my songs differ in volume from song to song depending on how they were ripped... therefore, often times, volume level 1 is too low, but volume level 2 is too loud... Therefore, i am looking for a pice of software that can turn down the volume on all my music files (mp3 and flac files) preferrably keeping the origional sound and bitrate settings... thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MP3Gain](http://mp3gain.sourceforge.net) can be used to normalize the levels on your songs so that they are all closer to the same volume.  You can manually set it to be lower than its recommended amount as well, which should accomplish what you want it to do.  The changes it makes are all in the file's metadata, so no recoding is necessary and it is completely reversible.  Not sure if it does flac files though...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with just about any desktop music application. I have used Foobar and iTunes to adjust the volume levels and saved the audio out of the application for external use. Give that a try.